# Slow response of DB2 on multiple JOINs in query by JDBC

Tags: java, sql, join, jdbc, db2

I have 3 different tables (without any primary or foreign key) in DB2 database as

```
CREATE TABLE XW (
    SRCLB VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    SRCFL VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    SRCMB VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    VARSQ DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (SRCLB, SRCFL, SRCMB, NAME, VARSQ) 
);

CREATE TABLE XO (
    LOBJ VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    LTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    ATTR VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    LTEXT VARCHAR(50),
    UNIQUE (LOBJ, LTYPE, ATTR) 
);

CREATE TABLE XM (
    LIB VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FILE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    MBR VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    SEQ DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    DTA VARCHAR(132),
    RECN INTEGER,
    UNIQUE (LIB, FILE, MBR, SEQ)
);
```

Each table having 2 lacs (appx) records. When I execute this query

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT XW.SRCMB
        ,XM.SEQ
        ,XM.DTA
        ,XM. FILE
        ,XM.LIB
        ,XO.TEXT
        ,XO.ATTR
    FROM
        (
            XW INNER JOIN XM
                ON (XW.VRECN = XM.RECN)
                AND (XW.SRCMB = XM.MBR)
                AND (
                    XW.SRCFL = XM. FILE
                )
                AND (XW.SRCLB = XM.LIB)
        )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XO
        ON (XW.SRCMB = XO.LOBJ)
WHERE
(XW.NAME = 'DB-NAME-A')
ORDER BY
XW.SRCMB
,XM.SEQ;
```

It returns the result in more than 15 seconds. But when I specify more columns in WHERE condition like

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT XW.SRCMB
        ,XM.SEQ
        ,XM.DTA
        ,XM. FILE
        ,XM.LIB
        ,XO.TEXT
        ,XO.ATTR
    FROM
        (
            XW INNER JOIN XM
                ON (XW.VRECN = XM.RECN)
                AND (XW.SRCMB = XM.MBR)
                AND (
                    XW.SRCFL = XM. FILE
                )
                AND (XW.SRCLB = XM.LIB)
        )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN XO
        ON (XW.SRCMB = XO.LOBJ)
WHERE
(XW.NAME = 'DB-NAME-A')
AND XW.SRCMB = 'CLCR0751'
AND XW.SRCFL = 'CBSRC'
AND XW.SRCLB = 'THPCOD_NEW'
ORDER BY
XW.SRCMB
,XM.SEQ;
```

Then the result comes in very quick time e.g. 2 seconds. **Can you suggest me what are the flaws in my Tables/Queries?**

**And how can I improve the performance of 1st query?**

**Would, using the Stored Procedure in place of SQL query be an advantage in this case???**

Thanks in advance

Kishore

Answer (score 4):

You do have an index on the `XW` table.  It is defined by the `unique` clause.  These are the columns in the index:  `SRCLB`, `SRCFL`, `SRCMB`, `NAME`, and then `VARSQ`.

In a `where` clause, the indexes has to be used from left to right -- the order of the columns makes a difference.  So, when you have a condition on `name`, the index cannot be used.

When you have a condition on `SRCLB`, `SRCFL`, `SRCMB`, and `SRNAME`, then the index can be used.

In addition, the data volume selected by the `where` clause after filtering is likely to be smaller with more equality conditions in the `where` clause, and that will also improve performance.

Comment: data can't be smaller as it varies from application to application. Could you suggest another clue?

Comment: @Kishore . . . Having four equality conditions in the `where` clause versus having just one would usually select less data.  Less data would often result in a faster query.

Comment: Would, using the Stored Procedure in place of SQL query be an advantage in this case???

Comment: @Kishore . . . In general, doing something with a `SELECT` statement is faster than using a cursor in a stored procedure.

Comment: Are the issue with 'INNER JOIN' and 'LEFT OUTER JOIN'?  since when I run the query for WHERE clause "SELECT * FROM XW WHERE XW.NAME = 'DB-NAME-A'", it hardly takes < 1 second.

Comment: @Kishore . . . The issue is partially related to the join.  When a database engine does a join, it often chooses one table to scan first.  The available indexes and their selectivity affect which is the driving table.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it's simply a matter of scale.

The WHERE clauses slice off pieces of each set.   The optimizer does those operations first, so by the time it starts on the JOINs there is simply less work to do.  It ought to be a function of the total number of rows returned.

You need to do a few things:

1. Run the DB2 equivalent of EXPLAIN PLAN to see if TABLE SCAN is being done.  If it is, perhaps you need more indexes
2. Create a VIEW and query that.  Amortize the JOIN time.
3. Ask yourself what records you really need.

Comment: As @duffymo said, you need to see what the optimizer is trying to do.  You mentioned no primary key and no indexes, which tells me there is most likely table scans occurring.  `Distinct` and `Order By` can greatly affect performance as well.  Your second `Select` has more `Where` clauses, meaning it is narrowing down the scope of each data set at each step.  Do be weary that executing through the client may be optimized differently than through JDBC.  I just ran into this issue with MS SQL where a select worked fine in the client, and killed the server through JDBC.

Comment: @duffymo, I just tried to execute the same query on the VIEWS instead of the tables. But this also consumes the same time.

Comment: Would, using the Stored Procedure in place of SQL query be an advantage in this case???

Comment: No, stored procedures just execute SQL in a more procedural style instead of relational.  Your problem is fundamental: too much data.

Comment: Are the issue with 'INNER JOIN' and 'LEFT OUTER JOIN'?  since when I run the query for WHERE clause "SELECT * FROM XW WHERE XW.NAME = 'DB-NAME-A'", it hardly takes < 1 second.

Comment: of course - a JOIN deals with two tables and more data.